# How do i remove the error in QtString. Am using pyqt4 and Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new in python and started working with PyQt to design a GUI application. I have succeeded to generate the python file but the following lines are generating errors:

```
_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
```

QString seems to be no longer in QtCore. How do I write the line? Below is part of the code

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s
```

Comment: This makes no sense at all. The code you've posted is automatically generated by `pyuic`. It will never show an error because the `try/except` block handles the exception if `QString` is missing. Have you attempted to edit the file? If so, that is always the wrong thing to do. Please read [this section](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/designer.html) of the pyqt docs to learn how to use `pyuic` correctly.

Comment: @ekhumoro i just realize it is the same and it was working. The problem PyQt configuration.  lambda s: s is the same  _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no QString now, Qt use unicode directly instead so replace it:

```
_fromUtf8 = lambda s: s
```

Comment: This isn't any different to the function definition already in the except block of the code in the OP...

Comment: @bigOTHER i replaced the try/except block with lambda s: s and PyCharm  no longer detects the error. but now the code